# Display Post Pagination - WP Custom Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I created a wp plugin which calls all posts from 2 categories then a filter which separates them into 4 subcategories. I cant't get the pagination to work - the code isn't broken but its not linking the posts to the next pages etc. and can’t figure out why this could be the case - so any pointers or possible reasons why this could be happening would be greatly appreciated.

I have gone through so many related questions and answers but nothing relating to plugin development. I've read and tried various variables in codex.wordpress but still no luck.

My query so far:

```
// Pagination
$totalPostsArgs = $queryArgs;
$totalPostsArgs['posts_per_page'] = -1;
$totalPostsFound = count(get_posts( $totalPostsArgs ));
$paginationArgs = array(
    'format' => '?category=' . $category . '&paged=%#%',
    'total' => ceil($totalPostsFound/$postsPerPage)
);
$postsHtml .= paginate_links( $paginationArgs );

return $postsHtml;
```

}

Comment: What is the output you are getting for `$postsHtml ` ?

Comment: Hi there, I'm getting 1 2 3 … 7 Next » on the front end.